# c++ / Qt - computation time

Tags: c++, qt

what is best way to measure computation time, with either STL C++ or Qt?

I know of ctime, but I have an idea Qt could be of use here.

Thanks!

Comment: Use `QElapsedTimer` and `:nsecsElapsed()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Theres the [QTime](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtime.html) class, that can measure time, you can start it via `start()` and retrieve it via the `elapsed()` method.

If you want something more advanced, you can go for [Boost.Chrono](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/doc/html/chrono.html) if you want to get into serious time perversions. It gets real hairy real quick though, and the doc is a bit sparse (as always with Boost), but it's really one of the cleanest and best libraries if you need something of that caliber.

It all depends on what you want to do though, because "measuring time of computation" is a very broad description. Do you actually want to **profile** your application? Then maybe a profiler tool might be more suitable.

Also, if you just want to get the raw time it takes to execute the program, there's the `time` command in Linux.

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I would use `QElapsedTimer`:

http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qelapsedtimer.html

Answer (score 0):

If you develop for **Windows**, you can use this from WINAPI:

```
DWORD start = ::GetTickCount();

calculation();

DWORD result = ::GetTickCount - start;
```

The DWORD `result` will contain the passed time in milliseconds.

*Note*: That this way of measuring is not uber precise. The precision varies between 10 and 16 ms. But if you just want to display something like "It took 5.37 seconds to calculate the meaning of life" it will suffice.